# What's the difference between 彼【かれ】 and あちら?

Tags: word-choice

The way I understand it 彼【かれ】 means 'that person over there' and あちら also means 'that person over there'

Comment: I think OP's talking about the あちら as in あちら(さま)は、どなた(ですか)？-- the politer version of あの人/あの方/あちらにいる人

Comment: For example, 彼は医者です and あちらは医者です.

Comment: こちら means this person, so I asume あちら means that person

Comment: When I look up the kanji word 医者 on my android japanese dictionary, in the example 彼は医者です, it's marked as かれ, but in the definition of the kanji itself 彼, it's marked as あれ, which is strange, because when typing あれ on my phone with a japanese keyboard, it doesn't give me a kanji substitute for it.

Comment: @Daniel, I assume your Android dictionary is using [WWWJDIC](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1C) as a source, and as I'm looking at it now, it does give あれ as the first reading for 彼, which is kind of messed up. You'll also note, though, that it's marked as an "archaic" reading. 彼 is almost always read かれ these days. I think part of the lesson here is that WWWJDIC is a community driven dictionary, and is usually right enough, but does have it's quirks, so use with care.

Comment: So, going back to my original question, what's the difference between 彼(かれ) and あちら?

Comment: 彼(かれ) means "he".  あちら has many meanings, including polite "that person (over there)". The plain way of saying "that person (over there)" is あの人.

Comment: Thanks, I've only done 私 and あなた up to now, so I didn't realize 彼 was the pronoun.  Thank for the help :)

Comment: You should think of words such as 私, あなた, 彼 etc as nouns, not pronouns. Syntactically they function exactly as other nouns. Also there are many ways of saying I, you, he etc in Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

彼 is strictly male and means "he" rather than "that person over there". Worth noting is that the he/she pronouns aren't as commonly used in Japanese as in English and 彼 can also mean "boyfriend". あちら is rather polite/stuffy for "that person (over there)" but it can also mean "over there" or "overseas".

> あちらがお父様ですか？ Is that (person standing over there) your father?

The most common expression for "that person" is however あの人, though it might be a little bit too casual depending on the context. A very impolite form that's sure to offend, on the other hand, is あいつ (or あのやつ).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation but in this case 彼 is 'he', あちら is 'that person'.
彼 is just a little bit more friendly, あちら is formal.